# Did I do anything wrong using convolution to solve this initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

I'm trying to use convolution to solve this problem:
$$y''+y= 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text0<t<\pi \\
0, & \text{t > }\pi
\end{cases}$$
$$y(0)=0$$ 
$$y'(0)=0$$

First I made the RHS into a unit step function:
$$y''+y=u(t)-u(t-\pi)+tu(t-\pi)$$
Then I took the Laplace of every term:
$$s^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0)+Y={1\over s}-{e^{-\pi s}\over s}+{e^{-\pi s}\over s^2}+{\pi e^{-\pi s}\over s^2+1}$$
Isolated Y
$$Y={1\over s}\cdot{1\over s^2+1}-{e^{-\pi s}\over s}\cdot{1\over s^2+1}+{e^{-\pi s}\over s^2}\cdot{1\over s^2+1}+{\pi e^{-\pi s}\over s}\cdot{1\over s^2+1}$$
Then for each term I chose a $G(s)$ and an $F(s)$. I think I made a mistake with this part.

1st term:
$$G(s)={1\over s} \Rightarrow g(t)=1$$
$$F(s)={1\over s^2+1} \Rightarrow f(t)=\sin t$$
2nd term:
$$F(s)={e^{-\pi s}\over s} \Rightarrow f(t)=u(t-\pi)$$
$$G(s)={1\over s^2+1} \Rightarrow g(t)=\sin t$$
3rd term:
$$F(s)={e^{-\pi s}\over s^2} \Rightarrow f(t)=(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)$$
$$G(s)={1\over s^2+1} \Rightarrow g(t)=\sin t$$
4th term:
$$F(s)={\pi e^{-\pi s}\over s} \Rightarrow f(t)=\pi u(t-\pi)$$
$$G(s)={1\over s^2+1} \Rightarrow g(t)=\sin t$$

I put all of them through the convolution integral $$(f*g)(t)=\int_0^tf(v)g(t-v)dv$$
I did a ton of work to solve all of them, and I had to use the trig identity $sin(t-v)=sint\;cosv-cost\;sinv$ for for three of the terms.

I ended up with this:
$$y=t+\sin t-\pi + \pi^2(1+\cos t)$$

Does this seem like a reasonable value? My friend told me that there should be a unit step function in the result, but he can't find what I did wrong. I apologize if there isn't enough work shown, there is just so much of it. If it's necessary I can add it in.

Comment: $+tu(t-\pi)$ is redundant and should be removed in your representation of the rectangular function.

Comment: I know it's the same solution as the 2nd term just multiplied by pi, I did make some unnecessary work for myself, but does it make a difference at the end when I simplify everything? I don't see how that could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the problem in terms of $u(t)$, it becomes

$$y''+y=u(t)-u(t-\pi)$$
Then
$$s^2Y-s\require{cancel}\cancel{y(0)}-\require{cancel}\cancel{y'(0)}+Y={1\over s}-{e^{-\pi s}\over s}$$
$$Y={1\over s}\left({1\over s^2+1}-{e^{-\pi s}\over s^2+1}\right)$$
Now applying the following property of the LT:

> $$\int_0^tf(x)dx\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}\longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{s}F(s)$$

yields

$$\begin{align}
y&=\int_0^t\left(\sin(x)-\sin(x-\pi)u(x-\pi)\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^t\sin(x)dx-u(t-\pi)\int_{\pi}^t\sin(x-\pi)dx\\
&=\int_0^t\sin(x)dx-u(t-\pi)\int_{\pi}^t-\sin(x)dx\\
&=-\cos(t)+1-u(t-\pi)\left(\cos(t)+1\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Two things, how is $tu(t- \pi)$ redundant? And I don't see any signs of convolution here (which according to instructions I need to use to solve the problem).

Comment: First: in your result with $tu(t-\pi)$ there is a ramp function for $t>\pi$, while we should have zero for $t>\pi$. 

Second: I used the properties of LT. Same result is achieved by convolution. Indeed, they are actually the same since convolution with a unit step is just an integration. So you can investigate $$f(t)\star u(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau$$ and if $f(t)=0$ for $t<0$, it becomes $$\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau$$